# TFS Task Group Admin Management

Tags: tfs

I know in TFS 2018, the ability to import/export task groups was made available to share task groups across different projects and collections. As a TFS admin trying to give a task group to all collections/projects, is there a way to create a task group that all collections/projects can use and I can update in one place and it be reflected everywhere?

I think the import/export is a step in the right direction, but would require me to maintain the task group in each project separately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task groups are stored at project level, and are not accessible outside the project scope. You would either import the task group manually on UI, or use REST api to program your own solution to import to other team projects.

The rest api is as below:

1. Get the task group from team project A

-

```
Get http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamprojectA/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskGroupId}?expanded=true
```

The response looks like below:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "tasks": [......]
        }
]
}
```

2. Import the task group to team Project B, the body part captures the "tasks" information from the response of above api

-

```
Post http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamprojectB/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups?api-version=4.0-preview.1

Content-Type:application/json

{
    "tasks": [......]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Task groups are configured per team project.

What you could do is to choose one as your template and then replicate it manually with export/import.